# how to create a sentence using words from user input

Tags: python, python-3.7

How would I create a sentence using words from user input?
I have a program right now that asks the user for a number and then based on that number, the user must type in that amount of words that then are supposed to come together to make a sentence. 
this is what I have so far:

```
howmany = (int (input ("How many words?\n>")))
for words in range (howmany):
        words = input ("Words please:\n>")
```

Comment: Can you post how the input and output should look like?

Comment: You are using `words` both as an index of a loop and the variable that you assign new input to. That is inconsistent. Furthermore, you are not saving any of the words. Perhaps tack them onto the end of a growing string?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please read a guide on how to write questions and what questions are supposed to go on StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give a try into this code, should work fine:

```
from __future__ import print_function

howmany = int (input ("How many words?\n>"))

words = []
for i in range (howmany):
    words.append(str(raw_input ("Words please:\n>")))

for word in words:
    print(word, end=' ')
```

Comment: Thanks... Could you please vote up and accept my answer, is very helpfull :D

Comment: one more question :| how would i then reverse the words in the sentence

Comment: You could do `word[::-1]` will reverse each word